# overflow warning as I try to do an add operation on the matrix cell

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I am seeing a weird warning , of which I have no clue what is going on. I am trying to do some operation on the image cell which looks like:

```
name = "./images/a.png" 
ci = cv2.imread(name)
img = cv2.cvtColor(ci, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# In the following statement, i and j correspond to the row and column respectively
op =  np.absolute(img[i, j+1] - img[i, j-1]) + np.absolute(img[i-1, j] - img[i, j-1])
```

As I run this statement, I get `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars`. I cannot understand the reason for it. Any idea what mistake am I making?

Answer (score 2):

It might have something to do with the type... try this

```
op =  np.absolute(int(img[i, j+1]) - int(img[i, j-1])) + np.absolute(int(img[i-1, j]) - int(img[i, j-1]))
```

a bit of clarification; `opencv` is using a type of `uint8` which has a range of 0-255.  Once adding 2 `unit8` values and they exceed 255, the encountered warning message is prompted

Comment: Could  you also explain, what does casting to `int` really do and if this is the best way to handle?

Comment: Using `int` is basically changing the representation of the value from an 8-bit to a larger representation.  Whether your values are integers or decimals, I’d err on the side of caution and use floats.  As for the loss of info, this won’t happen as long as the conversion is done before the calculation; change values to floats first then add/subtract/multiply/divide away